# Replace only leading NaN values in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of time series data, in which data reporting starts at different times (columns) for different observation units (rows). Prior to first reported datapoint for each unit, the dataframe contains `NaN` values, e.g.

```
    0   1   2   3   4 ...
A   NaN NaN 4   5   6 ...
B   NaN 7   8   NaN 10...
C   NaN 2   11  24  17...
```

I want to replace the leading (left-side) `NaN` values with `0`, but *only* the leading ones (i.e. leaving the internal missing ones as `NaN`. So the result on the example above would be:

```
    0   1   2   3   4 ...
A   0   0   4   5   6 ...
B   0   7   8   NaN 10...
C   0   2   11  24  17...
```

(Note the retained `NaN` for row B col 3)

I could iterate through the dataframe row-by-row, identify the first index of a non-`NaN` value in each row, and replace everything left of that with `0`. But is there a way to do this as a whole-array operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`notna` + `cumsum` by rows, cells with zeros are leading NaN:

```
df[df.notna().cumsum(1) == 0] = 0

df
     0    1   2     3   4
A  0.0  0.0   4   5.0   6
B  0.0  7.0   8   NaN  10
C  0.0  2.0  11  24.0  17
```

Comment: I like to use `cummax` with booleans ;) +1 I'd have done the same (with `cummax`)

Comment: @mozway is there a functional difference here?

Comment: @TYLim it keeps the array boolean and avoids internal conversion of the integers to booleans or doing a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `cumprod()` and `apply()`

```
s = df.isna().cumprod(axis=1).sum(axis=1)
df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(0,limit = s.loc[x.name]),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     0    1     2     3     4
A  0.0  0.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
B  0.0  7.0   8.0   NaN  10.0
C  0.0  2.0  11.0  24.0  17.0
```